# Accessing Google Api using Nodejs

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

I have scaffolded a web app which is able to register a user with Passportjs and Google Oauth2. While registering the user in the scopes I am asking for accessing the Google Plus API and retrieving the accessToken and refreshToken to be persisted in the MongoDB.

Later in the application I am trying to make an API call to retrieve Google Plus user profile to test . I am following the following steps in the code

var oAuth2 = googleCredentials.oauthClient(); // Setting a new Oauth2 // Client using  Project credentials

then retrieving the access_token and refresh_token for this particular user and setting the credentials like below

```
oAuth2.setCredentials({
      access_tokens: user[0].access_token,
      refresh_tokens: user[0].refresh_token
    });
```

then making an API call

```
  plus.people.get({
      userId: 'me',
      auth: oAuth2
    }, function (err, response) {

      console.log(err);
      res.send(response);

    });
```

but my application errors logging the following error

**[Error: No access or refresh token is set.]**

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I have even checked the validity of the access tokens by visiting the url https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=[my access token] and receive a positive response but really am not able to understand why does the API call always report an error a mentioned above. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Apologise for people who have spent time reading my code as it was such as obvious bummer . when setting the credentials I was passing plural words such as access_tokens instead of access_token and refresh_token. I spend an entire night trying to figure out the issue.

I am glad that I am able to proceed further.